# How to parse cURL postdata with PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing, curl

Is there any way to parse posts by `cURL` with `PHP`?

I have a PHP client what use this cURL call:

```
data1 = array(
    "email" => $email,
    "firstname" => $firstname,
    "lastname" => $lastname,
    "code" => $code
);
$data_string = json_encode($data1);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$passwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

How can I parse this cURL post on the server? I want to access to the JSON datas (CURLOPT_POSTFILEDS content).

It isn't in the $_POST or $_GET ... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It's available on standard input:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

`Content-Type` header you send in request makes PHP not to parse the POST body and make it available this way. So if in the future you wonder why it's missing, check your request for headers.

Comment: and what If there is nothing?

Comment: Well, there should be something. You can try to take the php client out and use cli: `curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}' http://server/api/method`. Do you see anything now?

Comment: this is in the http header: "* upload completely sent off: 2 out of 2 bytes\n< HTTP/1.1 200 OK" and after the header is running the echo file_get_contents('php://stdin') method, but there is nothing. Same if I send something in json data.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i Post curl data to my server:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_config['listener_file'] );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=".$data_enc."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

$data_enc is a json string;

this is how I read the data:

```
$_POST['data']
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the POST fields will be sent unless the curl request has:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

EDIT:
and use http_build_query instead of json_encode. post parameters are not JSON encoded.